# svnadmin: Premature end of content data

Tags: svn, repository, redmine

I'm trying to `svnadmin load` a dump into a new repository, and I get this message:

`svnadmin: Premature end of content data in dumpstream`

I'm also fairly certain that where the `load` ends is not the entire repository.  The last committed revision output by `svnadmin load` is 103, where I'm almost certain there were commits in the 400s+.  I was not part of the project in which the SVN holds their data, but I now have to load it onto a new svn host, and I'm fairly certain I'm missing a lot of data; but I can't be 100% sure.  The guy who did the dump is long gone, and I'm afraid so is the original repository.

Does this read like a corruption?  Is there any way of seeing more info from the dump file?  Or recovering data from this dump?  Did something happen to the data when he did the `svnadmin dump` in the first place?

When I search that error, I get weird results online, nothing seems straightforward to me regarding this particular error(?).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the exact format for the dump file and I couldn't find a description of it by searching.

If it is plain text, you can see by looking at the end of the file and check if the last line of the output is complete. If it is not, then the file is not complete.

Another possible indication of corruption is the file size. If the file size is a multiple of 512, then it is quite likely that it is corrupted. This is because it is the block size often used in program code, and only the last block of the file is incomplete.

It is hard to guess where the corruption has actually taken place. It can be an incomplete copy operation from source to destination, memory error, disk space running out etc.

Comment: Coincidentally I came to this post having a svn-dump of `105.283.584` bytes, divided by `512` its exactly `205.632` blocks of `512` bytes!!! **But: I made a recursive directory md5 on exported and imported and the repositorys differs!!!**

Comment: I made a new commit and exported the dump again and it imports like a charm because the new size div 512 isnt round. I reported a bug to svn-communtiy on http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3240872